# Python Appium Get Image from Android ImageView

Tags: python, android, imageview, appium

How can I get an image from an Android ImageView using Python Appium? This image should be in PNG format.

I want to test if an icon has the correct image and I fail to use the method `find_element_by_image` provided by Appium.

The `screenshot` method doesn't seem to be ideal for me because it takes a screenshot instead of giving me the original image, which would contain the white background while the original image doesn't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I didn't find a way to get the image but I have found a workaround to test the images.

You can use `element.screenshot(path)` to save the correct images to a local folder. (of course use `find_element_by_something` to get the element) Then save the images to compare using `element.screenshot(temp_path)`.

Finally, `from PIL import Image, ImageChops` and use `ImageChops.difference(Image.open(path1), Image.open(path2)) is None` for image comparison. The expression returns `True` if they match pixelwise.